# How to re-use Google Apps Scripts in new Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue. Whenever I create a new spreadsheet, I'm not able to add a script I've already created. The list for recent projects or scripts is always blank. Anyone have a resolution or do I always have to copy the script code and insert it into the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add your script as a library in the new spreadsheet. Lets start from the beginning. This sample code will add a string to the active cell:

```
function libTest(text) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  sh.setValue(text);
}
```

Save the script, by creating a version:
[image]

Next, copy the Project Key from the script editor:
[image]
[image]

Publish the script as a web app (execute only you):
[image]

In the new spreadsheet, open the script editor. Chose Manage Libraries from the resources option and enter and select the key/library:
[image]

In the script editor you can now add the following code:

```
function test(){
  libTest.libTest("jacobjan");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very clear and helpful.