# Use Google Apps script in a Spreadsheet from a separate .gs file

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am creating a series of spreadsheets that ought to perform some automation with Google Apps Script. Although the content of the spreadsheets differ, the scripts are the same.

I used to be able to write the script in a separate *.gs* file and import it as a library (as per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39604/how-to-re-use-google-apps-scripts-in-new-google-spreadsheet/)). Since Google updated the library functionality to addons, I can't find an option to run a script that is located in a standalone *.gs* file.

Google's documentation speaks about stand alone script, but only as *webapps* or *addons*. Is there a way to simply use the *.gs* in a similar way as I used the library?

e.g. `var name = lib.function(n)`

Comment: Library functionally is still available. Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries